# How do I check if the bot has permission to send messages in channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, permissions, discord.js

How can I check if the bot has permission to send messages in a channel?
This is what I tried:

```
      let test = "45673452348954"
   const test11 = client.channels.cache.get(test)
    if(client.user.permissionsIn(test1).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
      console.log("has permission")
```

Answer (score 4):

You did it correctly for the most part, the only thing that you messed up in is that it needs to be a GuildMember to check if it has permissions in a channel, not a user.

```
<Guild>.me.permissionsIn(test1).has("SEND_MESSAGES")
```